# How to access an element by its frequency in R?

Tags: r

```
-5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 
 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  1
```

I have this frequency table created using table function. Now I want to access the number using its frequency. For eg: If I enter frequency 2 it should give me 13

Answer (score 1):

Next time, please post a reproducible example. I assume you're working with something like this:

```
tt = table(c(1, 1, 2, 3))
```

The original values are now the names of this vector of counts, so you can do:

```
names(tt)[tt == 2]
# [1] "1"
```

But beware it is a `character` now, not a `numeric`.